# Convert to matrix but keep one diagonal to NULL in R

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse, stringdist

I have a huge dataset and that look like this.
To save some memory I want to calculate the pairwise distance but leave the
upper diagonal of the matrix to NULL.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringdist)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'stringdist'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     extract

df3 <- tibble(fruits=c("apple","banana","ananas","apple","ananas","apple","ananas"),
              position=c("135","135","135","136","137","138","138"), 
              counts = c(100,200,100,30,40,50,100))

stringdistmatrix(df3$fruits, method=c("osa"), nthread = 4) %>% 
  as.matrix()
#>   1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#> 1 0 5 5 0 5 0 5
#> 2 5 0 2 5 2 5 2
#> 3 5 2 0 5 0 5 0
#> 4 0 5 5 0 5 0 5
#> 5 5 2 0 5 0 5 0
#> 6 0 5 5 0 5 0 5
#> 7 5 2 0 5 0 5 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

However when I convert my stringdistmatrix to matrix (This step is essential for me),
my upper diagonal get filled with numbers.

**Is there anyway to convert to matrix but keep upper diagonal to NULL and save memory?**

I want my data to look like this

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6
2 5          
3 5 2        
4 0 5 5      
5 5 2 0 5    
6 0 5 5 0 5  
7 5 2 0 5 0 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to use sparse matrices. Package `Matrix` has such a possibility. You can learn more about sparse matrices at: [Sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)

```r
library(Matrix)

m <- sparseMatrix(i = c(1:3, 2:3, 3), j=c(1:3,1:2, 1), x = 1, triangular = T)

m

#> 3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dtCMatrix"
#>           
#> [1,] 1 . .
#> [2,] 1 1 .
#> [3,] 1 1 1
```

To check the size of the matrices, one can use function `object.size`.

It seems that for small matrices, using sparse matrices makes no difference, but, for large matrices, the memory savings are considerable:

```r
library(Matrix)

n <- 30
m1 <- matrix(1,n,n)
m2 <- Matrix(m1, sparse = TRUE) 

object.size(m1)
#> 7416 bytes

object.size(m2)
#> 7432 bytes

n <- 300
m1 <- matrix(1,n,n)
m2 <- Matrix(m1, sparse = TRUE) 

object.size(m1)
#> 720216 bytes

object.size(m2)
#> 544728 bytes
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned about memory, then `Matrix` may not be the answer, for two reasons:

- Distance matrices are *not* sparse. There are `n*(n-1)/2` nonredundant elements in an `n`-by-`n` distance matrix, and all of them can be nonzero. Asymptotically, that is half of the elements! It is inefficient to store these data in a `sparseMatrix` object, because, in addition to the nonzero elements, you need to store their positions in the matrix. Two integer vectors `i` and `j` of length `n*(n-1)/2` will occupy at least `4*n*(n-1)` bytes in memory (~10 gigabytes when `n = 5e+04`).
- `Matrix` implements class `dspMatrix` for efficient storage of dense symmetric matrices, including distance matrices. But whereas `dist` objects store the `n*(n-1)/2` elements below the diagonal, `dspMatrix` objects store those elements *and* the diagonal elements. So you can't coerce from `dist` to `dspMatrix` without allocating `4*n*(n+1)` bytes (again, ~10 gigabytes when `n = 5e+04`) for a new `n*(n+1)/2`-length double vector.

The most efficient approach is to preserve the `dist` object and index it directly, as needed for whatever computation you are doing.
You can take advantage of the fact that element `[i, j]` in the lower triangle of an `n`-by-`n` distance matrix is stored in element `[k]` of the corresponding `dist` object, where `k = i + (2 * (n - 1) - j) * (j - 1) / 2`.

For example, to get column (or row) `j` of the distance matrix specified by a `dist` object `x` *without* constructing the entire matrix, you could use this function:

```r
getDistCol <- function(x, j) {
    p <- length(x)
    n <- as.integer(round(0.5 * (1 + sqrt(1 + 8 * p)))) # p = n * (n - 1) / 2
    if (j == 1L) {
        return(c(0, x[seq_len(n - 1L)]))
    }
    ii <- rep.int(j - 1L, j - 1L)
    jj <- 1L:(j - 1L)
    if (j < n) {
        ii <- c(ii, j:(n - 1L))
        jj <- c(jj, rep.int(j, n - j))
    }
    kk <- ii + ((2L * (n - 1L) - jj) * (jj - 1L)) %/% 2L
    res <- double(n)
    res[-j] <- x[kk]
    res
}
```

```r
fruits <- c("apple", "banana", "ananas", "apple", "ananas", "apple", "ananas")
x <- stringdist::stringdistmatrix(fruits)
##   1 2 3 4 5 6
## 2 5          
## 3 5 2        
## 4 0 5 5      
## 5 5 2 0 5    
## 6 0 5 5 0 5  
## 7 5 2 0 5 0 5

getDistCol(x, 1L)
## [1] 0 5 5 0 5 0 5

lapply(1:7, getDistCol, x = x)
## [[1]]
## [1] 0 5 5 0 5 0 5
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 5 0 2 5 2 5 2
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 5 2 0 5 0 5 0
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 0 5 5 0 5 0 5
## 
## [[5]]
## [1] 5 2 0 5 0 5 0
## 
## [[6]]
## [1] 0 5 5 0 5 0 5
## 
## [[7]]
## [1] 5 2 0 5 0 5 0
```

If you insist on a `dspMatrix` object, then you can use this method to coerce from `dist`:

```r
library("Matrix")
asDspMatrix <- function(x) {
    n <- attr(x, "Size")
    i <- 1L + c(0L, cumsum(n:2L))
    xx <- double(length(x) + n)
    xx[-i] <- x
    new("dspMatrix", uplo = "L", x = xx, Dim = c(n, n))
}
asDspMatrix(x)
## 7 x 7 Matrix of class "dspMatrix"
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
## [1,]    0    5    5    0    5    0    5
## [2,]    5    0    2    5    2    5    2
## [3,]    5    2    0    5    0    5    0
## [4,]    0    5    5    0    5    0    5
## [5,]    5    2    0    5    0    5    0
## [6,]    0    5    5    0    5    0    5
## [7,]    5    2    0    5    0    5    0
```